# Gnuplot problem with linecolor palette heatmap

Tags: colors, gnuplot, line, heatmap

I am trying to plot lines (an XY plot), and I want to use the Y value to define the color of the line (greater than 0 should be red, lower than zero should be blue). However, I am unable of making gnuplot to recognize the Y value.
If I do not indicate in "using" a third column, then gnuplot plots all the values in the same colour, despite using "palette z" (see below).

This is my code:

```
set yrange [-2.5 : 2.5]  
set cbrange [-2.5:2.5]  
set palette maxcolors 2  
set palette defined (-2.5 'blue', 2.5 'red')  
set title 'Title'  
set xlabel 'X axis'  
plot 'file.csv' using 2:xtic(1) w l smooth csplines palette z dt 1, 'file.csv' using 3:xtic(1) w l smooth csplines palette z  dt 2, 'file.csv' using 4:xtic(1) smooth csplines palette z, 'file.csv' using 5:xtic(1) w l smooth csplines palette z  dt 4, 'file.csv' using 6:xtic(1) w l smooth csplines palette z dt 5
```

and produces the attached plot (line plot same color)

[image]

I have tried several ways of doing this, using `linecolor palette`, instead of `palette z`, in this case I get the error "not enough columns for variable color".

Also, I have tried adding a "z" value in using, for example: `using 2:xtic(1):2`. In this case, the plot goes weird and lines move right (see image) (line plot same color moved)

[image]

It looks like in the first case all the values are equal to zero (not Z value indicated).
I guess that the problem has to do with not indicating a "z" value in the first case, and in the second one could be that I am not indicating the "z" value correctly. My input data looks like this and I want that the values in the columns determine the color of the line:

| Data | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| R2 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 4 | -3 |
| R3 | -5 | -3 | -2 | 0.3 | -0.4 |
| R4 | ...... |  |  |  |  |
| R5 | ...... |  |  |  |  |
| R6 | ...... |  |  |  |  |
| R7 | ...... |  |  |  |  |

Also, I do not know if maybe an incompatibility of the smoothing function with the discrete paletter values could be a cause.

I have tried both terminal `pdfcairo` and `postscript`. Both give the same result. I am in a `multiplot` environment, and produce three of these in the same plot.

Any feedback and help is welcomed.
Thanks.
Juan

=== Edited question adding code because of problems with dashed patters. This code produces this result with multiplot ===

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced color font "Alegreya, 14" \
rounded size 1000,1700

set tmargin 2.5 
set bmargin 2 
set lmargin 7 
set rmargin 2

set encoding iso_8859_1
set output 'prueba.png'
set multiplot layout 3,1
set offset 0,0,graph 0.05, graph 0.05

set key autotitle column nobox sample 50 noenhanced
unset title
set style data lines

set datafile separator '\t'

reset session


#Plot1
#########
$Data <<EOD

A   -20.34  23.87   9.17    38.55   -35.57
B   -20.66  26.39   22.06   27.84   -43.68
C   -23.53  31.95   20.74   27.24   -35.15
D   -25.71  26.72   22.25   21.52   -40.87
E   -28.50  25.71   24.42   22.12   -36.21
F   -26.86  45.90   22.05   23.25   -46.15
G   -23.69  32.19   13.38   30.53   -39.58
H   -7.83   10.69   28.86   30.38   -45.29
I   -5.80   45.72   15.74   23.10   -43.97
J   -4.24   18.24   3.91    43.29   -45.87
K   -6.04   56.07   5.27    45.83   -31.82
L   -9.08   17.69   7.03    53.98   -31.84
EOD

set table $Smooth
    plot for [i=1:5] $Data u 0:i+1 w p smooth csplines
unset table

 set dashtype 1 '....'
 set dashtype 2 '. . '
 set dashtype 4 '-.-.'
 set dashtype 5 '_  _'

set yrange [-60 : 60]
set cbrange [-60:60]
set palette maxcolors 2
set palette defined (-50 'blue', 50 'red')
set ylabel "labelY"
unset colorbox
set key out above horiz noautotitle
set samples 5

plot $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 1, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 2, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 3,$Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 4, $Data u 0:(NaN):xtic(1)


reset session


#Plot2
#########
$Data <<EOD
A   -20.34  23.87   9.17    38.55   -35.57
B   -20.66  26.39   22.06   27.84   -43.68
C   -23.53  31.95   20.74   27.24   -35.15
D   -25.71  26.72   22.25   21.52   -40.87
E   -28.50  25.71   24.42   22.12   -36.21
F   -26.86  45.90   22.05   23.25   -46.15
G   -23.69  32.19   13.38   30.53   -39.58
H   -7.83   10.69   28.86   30.38   -45.29
I   -5.80   45.72   15.74   23.10   -43.97
J   -4.24   18.24   3.91    43.29   -45.87
K   -6.04   56.07   5.27    45.83   -31.82
L   -9.08   17.69   7.03    53.98   -31.84
EOD

set table $Smooth
    plot for [i=1:5] $Data u 0:i+1 w p smooth csplines
unset table

 set dashtype 1 '....'
 set dashtype 2 '. . '
 set dashtype 4 '-.-.'
 set dashtype 5 '_  _'

set yrange [-60 : 60]
set cbrange [-60:60]
set palette maxcolors 2
set palette defined (-50 'blue', 50 'red')
set ylabel "labelY"
unset colorbox
set key out above horiz noautotitle
set samples 5

plot $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 1, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 2, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 3,$Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 4, $Data u 0:(NaN):xtic(1)

reset session


#Plot3
#########
$Data <<EOD
A   -20.34  23.87   9.17    38.55   -35.57
B   -20.66  26.39   22.06   27.84   -43.68
C   -23.53  31.95   20.74   27.24   -35.15
D   -25.71  26.72   22.25   21.52   -40.87
E   -28.50  25.71   24.42   22.12   -36.21
F   -26.86  45.90   22.05   23.25   -46.15
G   -23.69  32.19   13.38   30.53   -39.58
H   -7.83   10.69   28.86   30.38   -45.29
I   -5.80   45.72   15.74   23.10   -43.97
J   -4.24   18.24   3.91    43.29   -45.87
K   -6.04   56.07   5.27    45.83   -31.82
L   -9.08   17.69   7.03    53.98   -31.84
EOD

set table $Smooth
    plot for [i=1:5] $Data u 0:i+1 w p smooth csplines
unset table

 set dashtype 1 '....'
 set dashtype 2 '. . '
 set dashtype 4 '-.-.'
 set dashtype 5 '_  _'

set yrange [-60 : 60]
set cbrange [-60:60]
set palette maxcolors 2
set palette defined (-50 'blue', 50 'red')
set ylabel "labelY"
unset colorbox
set key out above horiz noautotitle
set samples 5

plot $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 1, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 2, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z, $Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 3,$Smooth using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 4, $Data u 0:(NaN):xtic(1)

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: What are your x-values? Numerical values 0,1,2... or string values R1,R2,R3,... ?

Comment: Hi theozh, my x-values are the strings: R1, R2... in this order, and the y-values are those in the columns. I plot 5 lines with the values of the columns.

Comment: you are always plotting the whole datablock `$Smooth` and not just the subblocks one after each other, i.e. `plot $Smooth u 1:2:2 index 0 w l lc palette z dt1, $Smooth u 1:2:2 index 1 w l lc palette z dt 2, ...`   Check `help index`.

Comment: Solved. Feeling quite stupid right now. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear. If my answer solved your problem, please check the check mark at the top left of the answer, indicating that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `smooth` and variable linecolor (`lc var`) or `palette z` don't work together. So, I would suggest to write the smoothed data into a datablock first. Then address the subblocks via `index`.

- be aware, if you set `samples` to high the dashed pattern might resemble a solid line again.
- you have to set the xtics in a separate dummy plot by plotting nothing, i.e. `NaN`.

**Script:**

```
### smooth and conditional color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 R1    6.1    2.2    1.3    7.4    3.5
 R2    3.1   -5.2   -4.3    9.4   -7.5
 R3   -5.1    7.2    2.3    5.4    5.5
 R4    2.1    3.2    6.3   -7.4   -2.5
 R5    7.1    9.2    3.3    4.4    4.5
EOD

set table $Smooth
    plot for [i=1:5] $Data u 0:i+1 w p smooth csplines
unset table

set yrange  [-10:10]
set cbrange [-10:10]
set palette maxcolors 2
set palette defined (-2.5 'blue', 2.5 'red')
set xlabel 'x axis'
unset colorbox
set key out noautotitle
set samples 50

plot for [i=0:4] $Smooth u 1:2:2 index i w l lc palette z dt i+1 ti sprintf("C%d",i+1), \
     $Data u 0:(NaN):xtic(1)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It seems to work. However, I have a problem with the dashing of the lines. Independently of the sample value, all of them look the same, solid lines. I have changed slightly the plot syntax to use my own defined dashed types and the names of the columns that are not 1,2,3...    plot $Smoothdata using 1:2:2 w l dt 1 lc palette z ti sprintf("C1"), $Smoothdata using 1:2:2 w l lc palette z dt 2 ti sprintf("C2"),..., $Data u 0:(NaN):xtic(1)   Any idea?

Comment: @aetherlux hmm, what terminal size and linewidth? Can you maybe edit your question and post the script and the graph you get?

Comment: thanks again for the help. I have edited the question with the code and the resulting image. I tried several terminals, for example, postscript and pngcairo. Despite indicating linetype or dashtype, it does not work with the current plot command. If I use other plot options, it works. Actually, the key above the plots shows the dashed lines.